# How I can set Content-Type in react to application/json

Tags: java, reactjs, http

My React code as down below

[image]

and it always turn to text/plain;charset=UTF-8

[image]

I found that cors support just

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain
```

but I want to send the json to Http req. how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the wrong HTTP header to accept JSON as a response. The header you should set is Accept:

```
axios.get('my/url', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         Accept: 'application/json'
    }
})
```